# Android: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library

Tags: android, flutter, manifest-merging

I have an Android (Java) source code, in which I have integrated the Flutter module. When I run my Android application in Android Studio I get the following error. I know the solution is very straightforward. Perhaps the error itself suggests the solutions. However, I can't implement those solutions as I get the following error for multiple flutter packages I am using, in my Flutter source code. How do I resolve this without changing minSdkVersion in the Android app?

Let me explain the structure of the source code I have.

```
--Android_A  --- It has all the Android source code
--Flutter_B  --- It has flutter code
    --Flutter_C  --- It is a git submodule with flutter source code again.
```

The `pubspec.yaml` inside each flutter module above has a line indicating the dependencies. E.g

`Flutter_C/pubspec.yaml` has the following line

```
Flutter_B:
     path: ../../Flutter_B
```

Similarly `Flutter_B/pubspec.yaml` has the following line

```
Flutter_C:
     path: Flutter_C
```

Finally, Android_A/settings.gradle has the following lines.

```
include ':app'
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
evaluate(new File(
        settingsDir.parentFile,
        'Flutter_B/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
))
```

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:payu_checkoutpro_flutter] 
~/pm_module/.android/plugins_build_output/payu_checkoutpro_flutter/intermediates/merged_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.payubiz.payu_checkoutpro_flutter" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I tried changing minSdkVersion as the error suggests, but unfortunately, I receive this error for so many packages.
There are other SO posts similar to this problem, but they are also talking about a single package.

**It was working well in the current setup, it suddenly started throwing this issue**.
I even ran the `git reset` and `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and similar commands.

Comment: Did you upgrade one of your packages? Or Flutter itself? It would help to see your pubspec.yaml file. I would advise you to look at all the packages you have and find out which one has the lower API level declared.

Comment: @tomerpacific let me update my question with some more information.

Comment: You haven't shared your pubspec.yaml or build.gradle files to see your dependencies.

Comment: Those files are too big to share here. I assume I have shared the related information from those files above. I can share that snippet if you can tell me what specific information you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you can enable multidex support in your Android project. Multidex support allows your app to build and run on older Android versions that have a limitation on the number of methods in a single dex file. To enable multidex, follow these steps :
In your `build.gradle` file (typically located in the `android/app` directory), add the following lines inside the `android` block:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to include the multidex dependency in your `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Finally, update your `AndroidManifest.xml` to include the multidex application class :

```
<application
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Hi Fares, I am just curious, why do you think the problem is related to no. of methods in a single file?

Comment: Because before I had this problem and this is trying to work around the problem by making changes to the general configuration of the Android application to see if that also fixes the manifest merging problem.

Comment: It did not help. :(